# How does a disassembler work and how is it different from a decompiler?

Tags: cpu-architecture, decompiler, disassembly

I'm looking into installing a disassembler (or decompiler) on my Linux Mint 17.3 OS and I wanted to know what the difference is between a disassembler and a decompiler. I have a rough idea of what they are (the names are fairly self-explanatory), but they are still a bit confusing.

I've read that a disassembler turns a program into assembly language, which I don't know, so it seems kind of useless to me. I've also read that a decompiler turns a 'binary file' into its source code. What exactly is a binary file?

Apparently, decompilers cannot decompile to C, only Python and other similar languages. So how can I turn a program into its original C source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A disassembler is a pretty straightforward application that transfers *machine code* into *assembly language statements* - This activity is the reverse operation that an *assembler* program does and is straightforward because there is a strict one-to-one relationship between machine code and assembly. A disassembler aims at a specific CPU. The original assembler that was used to create the executable is only of minor relevance.

A decompiler aims at recreating a compiled high-level language program from machine code into its original format - Thus trying the reverse operation of a C or Forth (popular languages for which de-compilers exist) compiler. Because there are so many high-level languages and thus so many ways in how original high-level language constructs could be expressed in machine code (even a lot of different strategies for the same language and construct, even in the same compiler, and even different strategies depending on the compiler mode and situation), this operation is much more complex and very dependent on the original compiler (and maybe even the command line that was used, it's chosen optimization level and also the used version).

Even if all that fits, most of the work of a decompiler is educated guessing and will most probably never reach a point where it can reconstruct the original program in its source code form 100% - It will rather end up with a *version of source code that could have been the original program*.

Comment: Ohh, that makes much better sense now. So does that mean ideally one should get a decompiler that is specific to the original compiler and command line that were used (provided they are known) when writing the program? For example, a decompiler that converts programs assuming they used GCC and Linux terminal.

Comment: Maybe also worth mentioning the *version* of the compiler.

Comment: @jpmc26 read more carefully ;) Second para, last sentence in brackets